# Arduino Package for Octave

Tags: arduino, octave

I've been trying to make [this package](https://octave.sourceforge.io/arduino/index.html) work on my laptop but no luck so far. I'm currently running Arduino IDE 1.8.7 and Octave 4.4 on KDE Neon 5.14.
So the thing is, when I enter the arduinosetup() function in the command window in Octave, the Arduino IDE displays the opening screen for 2 seconds then exits, and I get the following code in my command window in Octave:

```
>> pkg list
Package Name        | Version | Installation directory
--------------------+---------+-----------------------
           arduino  |   0.2.0 | /home/neon/octave/arduino-0.2.0
instrument-control  |   0.3.1 | /home/neon/octave/instrument-control-0.3.1

>> pkg load arduino

>> arduinosetup('arduinobinary', '/opt/arduino/arduino')
Running "/opt/arduino/arduino" "/tmp/oct-yktW7j/octave/octave.ino"
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:
java.lang.Error: Cannot load com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel
        at javax.swing.UIManager.initializeDefaultLAF(UIManager.java:1351)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.initialize(UIManager.java:1459)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.maybeInitialize(UIManager.java:1426)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.getLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:492)
        at processing.app.linux.GTKLookAndFeelFixer.installGtkPopupBugWorkaround(GTKLookAndFeelFixer.java:79)
        at processing.app.linux.Platform.setLookAndFeel(Platform.java:44)
        at processing.app.Base.<init>(Base.java:239)
        at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:145)
ans = 0

>>
```

The Arduino IDE is installed in the /opt folder and Octave was installed via flatpak. Also openjdk 10.0.2 is installed and I have tried uploading many scripts to my arduino via the Arduino IDE and they were successful so no problem there.
Does anyone have any solution for this problem?

Comment: Is the arduino IDE running (and able to program) without Octave? Sounds like a missing JRE? Also consider asking in the octave hell mailingslist where you'll find the package author and maintainer

Comment: Yes, it runs and I'm able to upload my scripts to my arduino successfully. I have the JRE installed in the '/usr/lib/jvm' folder under the name 'jre1.8.0_192'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is looking for the gtk look and feel, which you probally don't have with kde. You can change the Arduino script file

/opt/arduino/arduino

line:

```
JAVA_OPTIONS=("-DAPP_DIR=$APPDIR" "-Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel")
```

to

```
JAVA_OPTIONS=("-DAPP_DIR=$APPDIR")
```

And it wont try to load it